# PHP / Javascript create new inputs depend the value that given by user

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am creating a project where the user gives some numbers and, after he press the button, the next page will show some tables, that I want to have as input fields as the number that the user gave previously.

Here is the form with the number that user gives:

```html
<form action="9660egmeters.php" method="post">
<table>

<tr>
    <td>M 9660 European Groove</td>
    <td>Μ/Φ</td>
    <td>Δ/Φ</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Ποσότητα</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="value1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="value2"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Διαφορετικά Μεγέθη</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="diff1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="diff2"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Πόρτες</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="doors1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="doors2"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Παράθυρα</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="windows1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="windows2"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Πατζούρι</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="shutter1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="shutter2"></td>
</tr>


</table>

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here is the next tables that I want inside them to  create the new input fields, depending the number that the users gives for each one.

```php
<?php

//ΥΨΟΣ ΠΛΑΤΟΣ ΟΛΩΝ ΑΥΤΩΝ ΠΟΥ ΕΧΕΙ ΕΠΙΛΕΞΕΙ

$value1 = $_POST["value1"];
$value2 = $_POST["value2"];
$diff1 = $_POST["diff1"];
$diff2 = $_POST["diff2"];
$doors1 = $_POST["doors1"];
$doors2 = $_POST["doors2"];
$windows1 = $_POST["windows1"];
$windows2 = $_POST["windows2"];
$shutter1 = $_POST["shutter1"];
$shutter2 = $_POST["shutter2"];

?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td> 
        <td>ΠΛΑΤΟΣ</td>
        <td>ΥΨΟΣ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Παράθυρα Μ/Φ χωρίς Παντζούρι</td>  
<!---------here I want the new inputs----->
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td> 
        <td>ΠΛΑΤΟΣ</td>
        <td>ΥΨΟΣ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Παράθυρα Μ/Φ με Παντζούρι</td>  
<!---------here I want the new inputs----->
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td> 
        <td>ΠΛΑΤΟΣ</td>
        <td>ΥΨΟΣ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Πόρτα Μ/Φ χωρίς Παντζούρι</td>  
<!---------here I want the new inputs----->
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td> 
        <td>ΠΛΑΤΟΣ</td>
        <td>ΥΨΟΣ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Πόρτα Μ/Φ με Παντζούρι</td>  
<!---------here I want the new inputs----->
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td> 
        <td>ΠΛΑΤΟΣ</td>
        <td>ΥΨΟΣ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Παράθυρο Δ/Φ χωρίς Παντζούρι</td>
<!---------here I want the new inputs-----> 
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td> 
        <td>ΠΛΑΤΟΣ</td>
        <td>ΥΨΟΣ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Παράθυρο Δ/Φ με Παντζούρι</td>  
<!---------here I want the new inputs----->
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td> 
        <td>ΠΛΑΤΟΣ</td>
        <td>ΥΨΟΣ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Πόρτα Δ/Φ χωρίς Παντζούρι</td> 
<!---------here I want the new inputs-----> 
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td> 
        <td>ΠΛΑΤΟΣ</td>
        <td>ΥΨΟΣ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Πόρτα Δ/Φ με Παντζούρι</td>  
<!---------here I want the new inputs----->
    </tr>
</table>
```

In other posts, I find how to create new inputs with a button, but I didn't find how to do it automatically depending on some numbers coming from the previous page.

Comment: What is stopping you? Why did you tag jQuery? Looks like a simple PHP loop to me

Comment: because ,it could be happen with jQuery too, if some1 knows how

Comment: Please give example input and expected output and show what code you have tried so far

Comment: The inputs are simple decimal positive numbers , like 1,2,3,4.

Comment: And the output wanna be new inputs the are depended on that numbers. If he gives number 3 i new 3 inptus on the table

Comment: And if I enter 2 in a field, what do I see on the next page and if I enter 2 in one field and 3 in another, what do I see on the next page? Can you please help us help you?

Comment: Each field corresponds to a specific output so its not a prob.

Comment: And what exactly do you need from us now? If you don’t know how a basic _loop_ works, then you should perhaps be consulting a beginner tutorial right now?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

I do not read Greek so I do not know what exactly you want

```js
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let html = [];

  $(":input").each(function(i) {
    let num = this.value;
    if (num !== "" && !isNaN(num)) {
      num = +num;
      html.push(`<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>ΠΛΑΤΟΣ</th>
      <th>ΥΨΟΣ</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tb${i}">
    <tr>
        <td>Παράθυρα Μ/Φ χωρίς Παντζούρι</td>`)
      for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        html.push(`<td><input type="text" name="${this.name}" value="" /></td>`)
      }
      html.push(`</tr></tbody></table>`);
      $("#output").html(html.join(""));
      console.log(html)
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="9660egmeters.php" method="post">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>M 9660 European Groove</th>
        <th>Μ/Φ</th>
        <th>Δ/Φ</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tb1">
      <tr>
        <td>Ποσότητα</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="value1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="value2"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Διαφορετικά Μεγέθη</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="diff1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="diff2"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Πόρτες</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="doors1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="doors2"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Παράθυρα</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="windows1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="windows2"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Πατζούρι</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="shutter1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="shutter2"></td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
<hr/>
<div id="output"></div>
```